# Embedded fonts with polish characters

Tags: css, embed, typography, fonts

There are many font banks out there. But where I can fonts with polish characters ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your polish fonts, you can generate your font-face easily

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Comment: Assuming the font is licensed for web use. Most fonts aren't or require you to purchase a separate web license--in which case they usually provide you with the appropriate formats.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Polish type foundries there are, but any Unicode typeface should have Polish characters, I beleive. Here's a list of free (as in speech) ones you can use with the FontSquirrel generator goker.cebeci linked to:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software_Unicode_typefaces

However, it should be noted that Unicode fonts are typically much larger than regular fonts because they contain so many glyphs. There are font editing tools that let you remove unused glyphs (generally a bad idea, but may be excusable in this case), but you'll need to ask those questions on the [Graphic Design StackExchange site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).